# Как сделать скрол вниз?

Tags: c#, парсер, anglesharp

Если в двух словах то я никак не пойму как делать скрол в низ, либо подгружать контент на таких сайтах как вк(стенки), pinterest.com или deviantart.com.
Страницу загружаю парсю, но там не весь контент и как его догрузить чтоб допарсить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываешь в браузере инструменты веб-разработчика, раздел Сеть. Открываешь целевой сайт. После окончания загрузки страницы в панельке Сеть очищаешь список появившихся там запросов и скроллишь вниз страничку. В какой-то момент будет начата догрузка контента. На панельке Сеть появится новый список запросов? инициированных догрузкой. Тебе нужен самый первый Post/Get, который запрашивает html или plain/text.
Выбираешь его, остается только скрупулёзно изучать заголовки этого запроса и URL куда он улетел.

Дальше всё примитивно, создаешь `WebRequest`, у него в свойствах копируешь все критичные заголовки изученного выше запроса и остаётся выполнить `GetResponse()` => `WebResponse` => `GetResponseStream()` => `Stream` => `StreamReader` => целевой `string`.

Если в ответе видишь мусор, то данные были сжаты, используй автоматическую декомпрессию. Когда будешь изучать запрос догрузки контента при скроллинге/пагинации смотри не только на заголовки запроса, но и на его тело, в большинстве случаев именно там все интересующие тебя зависимости. Ну и плюс сам target URL может различаться от страницы к странице в пределах одного домена.

Можно сразу юзать `HttpWebRequest`, если этого тебе будет достаточно. Про `HttpClient` придется забыть. И вот тут я наконец разул глаза и увидел, что вопрос про AngleSharp, отправлю, зря печатал что ли. AngleSharp core скроллить не умеет, поддержка планировалась в AngleSharp.Scripting, но не знаю, реализовал ли её автор к текущему моменту.